# two tables 1 dataset and pass to datagridview ,Incorrect syntax near keyword as using vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have an error regarding joining two tables and 1 dataset and pass to datgridview.. Im a noob. my flow is i want to display the selected column in two tables and display in single datagridview row.. my query runs at sql server management studio but when i code it in vb.net it cause an error.. pls help me..

This is my code in sql server management studio:

```
Select a.CeramicLotNo,a.CeramicPartsNo, b.CerlotNo,b.MoldingLot
            from tblHikLotMgtDB as a
            INNER JOIN tblHikConchart as b
            On a.CeramicLotNo = b.CerlotNo
            where b.CerLotNO = 'W13D004-015'
```

then this is my code in vb.net

```
 Private Sub btnHiSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHiSearch.Click
        cerlot = Trim(txtHiSearch.Text)
        dgrid.Rows.Clear()

    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=ITS-CODER02\DIBMART; Initial Catalog = HiKLotMgt; User Id= sa; Password = !@#;")
    con.Open()


    sql = "Select a.CeramicLotNo,a.CeramicPartsNo, b.CerlotNo,b.MoldingLot" & _
       "from tblHikLotMgtDB as a" & _
       "INNER JOIN tblHikConChart as b" & _
       "On a.CeramicLotNo = b.CerlotNo" & _
       "where a.CeramicLotNo = '" & cerlot & "'"
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da.Fill(ds, "tblHikLotMgtDB")
    da.Fill(ds, "tblHikConChart")

    ds.Tables("tblHikLotMgtDB").TableName = "tblHikLotMgtDB"
    ds.Tables("tblHikConChart").TableName = "tblHikConChart"
    dgrid.Rows.Add(ds.Tables("tblHikLotMgtDB").Columns("CeramicPartsNo"), ds.Tables("tblHiKLotMgtDB").Columns("CeramicLotNo"), ds.Tables("tblHikConChart").Columns("MoldingLot"), ds.Tables("tblHikConChart").Columns("CerLotNo"))
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because poster appears to think posting code other than that which is running is fine.


Comment: The problems is solved.. but i got another logical error in ds.Tables("tblHikLotMgtDB").TableName = "tblHikLotMgtDB"
    ds.Tables("tblHikConChart").TableName = "tblHikConChart"
    dgrid.Rows.Add(ds.Tables("tblHikLotMgtDB").Columns("CeramicPartsNo"), ds.Tables("tblHiKLotMgtDB").Columns("CeramicLotNo"), ds.Tables("tblHikConChart").Columns("MoldingLot"), ds.Tables("tblHikConChart").Columns("CerLotNo"))
    con.Close()....

Answer (score 0):

You have missing spaces between the line parts of your query:

```
"Select a.CeramicLotNo,a.CeramicPartsNo, b.CerlotNo,b.MoldingLot" & _
   "from tblHikLotMgtDB as a" & _
    ^
```

Add a space either at the end of each line or start of next  line. Or concatenate each line with `vbCrLf`

Comment: I already put space and it runs already in a datagridview but the problems.. my datagridview doesnt pass the data in the dataset

Comment: That comment made ZERO sense.  Are you running the code you posted, or wasting everyone's time?

Comment: wait, sorry.. i dont waste everyones time.. pls help me.. i will put my output program with error..

Comment: first problem is solved... this is cause logical error.. ds.Tables("tblHikLotMgtDB").TableName = "tblHikLotMgtDB"
    ds.Tables("tblHikConChart").TableName = "tblHikConChart"
    dgrid.Rows.Add(ds.Tables("tblHikLotMgtDB").Columns("CeramicPartsNo"), ds.Tables("tblHiKLotMgtDB").Columns("CeramicLotNo"), ds.Tables("tblHikConChart").Columns("MoldingLot"), ds.Tables("tblHikConChart").Columns("CerLotNo"))

Comment: mitch im sorry.. your suggestion works fine but i got another error which doesnt relate with the headline problem.. sorry for the inconvinience,